# Unabe to install Watchdog

Tags: python, pip, watchdog

**I have not been able to install watchdog for windows...**

I have tried the following:

1. Download watchdog-0.8.2.tar.gz
2. Copy the above  *.tar.gz to C:\Python27\Scripts
3. Added C:\Python27\Scripts to system environmental variables
4. Added C:\Program Files\7-Zip (install location for 7-zip) to system
   environmental variables
5. In CMD Prompt:  cd C:\Python27\Scripts
6. c:\Python27\Scripts> 7z x watchdog-0.8.2.tar.gz
7. pip install watchdog
8. from python IDE: import watchdog
9. receive this error: No module named watchdog

Any recommendations are welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Nobody? Surely somebody has installed this before?

Comment: Is your IDE using the version of Python from the directory in which you install watchdog?